# Can't exclusively bind to the network port with boost asio

Tags: c++, boost, network-programming, boost-asio

I develop server app using boost asio. App works great. What doesn't work, is the the exclusive binding to the network port.

Example:

```
void testPortBinding()
{
    boost::asio::io_service _ioService;
    int serverPort = 10000;
    auto endpoint = boost::asio::ip::tcp::endpoint(boost::asio::ip::tcp::v4(), serverPort);
    boost::shared_ptr<boost::asio::ip::tcp::acceptor> tcpAcceptor(new boost::asio::ip::tcp::acceptor(_ioService, endpoint));

    boost::this_thread::sleep(boost::posix_time::time_duration(0, 0, 30, 0));
}

int main()
{
    testPortBinding();

    return 0;
}
```

For example we launched two instances of such app at the same time. Both processes bind to the network port and sleep for 30 seconds.

Using tab `Network` of Windows tool `Resource Monitor` we see that the first launched process listening on the network port `10000` and second process do not listening any port.
Right after first process stopped - second process starts to listening on the network port `10000`.

So it looks like the second process waits until the first process stopped listening on TCP port.

Desired behavior: app binds to the TCP port or stops if TCP port already used.
So in this test case second process should stop with exception.

How to achieve such behavior?

Comment: You could post the answer as an answer yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is simple - we need to set option `reuse_address` to false. `new boost::asio::ip::tcp::acceptor(_ioService, endpoint, false)` works perfect. Description for this option - [asio docs](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/socket_base/reuse_address.html)